# Attach anchor point to other object

Tags: premiere, animation, adobe

I have a text and an arrow, and I want them to follow a simple path. I have animated the arrow with a few keyframes and I'm happy with it.

Now I would like my text to follow the exact same motion, so my idea would be to just somehow "attach" its anchor point to the arrow object, and turn on the animation button, and "voila".

Is that possible in any way? How do I achieve this without copy pasting the animation from the previous object ? What is the efficient and smart way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

- select both layers
- press "p"
- in the text layer, drag the whip (the little curly thing)
- drop it on the position, or the anchor of the arrow, depending on which one has keyframes.
- voila.

You can also adjust the anchor of the text to shift it and still make it follow the arrow.

Comment: I'm not currently able to test, but what is P the shortcut of?

Comment: It's "p" for position

Comment: Okay I just had a chance to try out ; I'm not sure I follow you though.
So to make things clear, with my hotkeys pressing P selects the Pen tool. Also, I didnt find any "whip" or anything curly in the text layer (not sure where exactly), apart from the "Reset" icon on the right hand side of each effect. Could you clarify a little more please ?

Comment: I believe Florian is referring to After Effects - not Premiere. AFAIK, there are no whips in Premiere. Florian is correct in implying that this process is better suited to do in After Effects and not directly in premiere - as there's far more options available for motion controls in AE.

The new Essential Graphics options would be ideal to work (theoretically) seamlessly from AE to Premiere. 

If you're not comfortable working in AE, doing it by hand in Premiere might be your only option.

Comment: I'm incredibly sorry, I was assuming you meant after effects since that's usually used for this kind of motion graphic design. Indeed, keyframing it by hand would be your only option in premiere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this in Premiere that I can think of.

I tried nesting a track, then masking it and tracking the mask, but it doesn't help: you can track mattes in Premiere, but there's no way to copy the keyframed data from one track to another, or convert it into position keyframes.

If anyone can think of a work-around, I'd be interested to see it.